# Apostrophe is converting as &#039;

Tags: sql, encoding, character-encoding, siebel

I have a table in which there is a column of type long.
In this column, we have stored the email responses. Now the problem which i am facing while querying business component which is on this table, is that the character `'` is automatically getting converted to `&#039;`
As shown in example below:
Value in column:

```
We've noticed some unusual usage on your phone.
```

Value coming while querying the Business Component:

```
We&#039;ve noticed some unusual usage on your phone.
```

Although if i query in database directly, i am able to see ' correctly.

Can anyone suggest how this is happening ?
Thanks

Comment: 1)remove the `security` from text inserted in db or 2)change all `&#039;` to `'`

Comment: @user3508453 I am not inserting the data in db instead i am querying the data from it.

Comment: then when u echo em out just replace

Comment: @user3508453 Yes that is a workaround. But as of now i am more inquisitive to know the cause of this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above link is related to Siebel.
So i will place my answer w.r.t Siebel. There is templates for communicating users in CRM.
Now if you do not mark `HTML Template`, then it will not convert the content of the body in `UTF-8` format.
Since the HTML Type was unmarked in your case, speical character was not getting converted.

Mark it and your problem will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

The template from which this field was picking up the value, we not in HTML Template format. For handling special characters like ', this property need to be marked.

Detailed info here : [ExternalLink](http://siebel78.blogspot.in/2014/06/importance-of-html-template-in-template.html)